# Unable to add Facebook to Online Accounts in 17.04 Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, system-settings, facebook, online-accounts

Esteemed fellow Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 users,
I'm trying to add Facebook to online accounts and the first time I try I get the usual login window. However when I enter all the data the account is not created in online accounts. Each time I try after that I just get a brief blank window. Can anyone advise what might be going wrong? Sadly I don't get any error messages so can't help you there.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first suggestion is, as always, fully update your system and try again.

Comment: Thank you. I can confirm that my system is completely up-to-date. For additional info, I wondered if any previous settings were causing my issue. So I went to "apps" in Facebook and deleted the Ubuntu and Gnome apps I found there. I then tried again to add Facebook to Online Accounts. Again on the first attempt I see the Facebook login screen and everything seems fine, but the account is not added to Online Accounts. I checked again in Facebook and the Gnome app is added. If I subsequently try to re-add Facebook I get a fleeting blank screen.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. I'm also running Ubuntu Gome 17.04, fully up to date. I also tried to remove app on Facebook and add it back but it won't appear on the list of online accounts after clicking accept on the pop-up. (I tried Google and Pocket, they are successfuly added).